# Adding a LIKE Operator in WHERE Clause (Dynamic SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, dynamic-sql, sql-like

I'm using Dynamic SQL to create a 'SELECT' SQL statement which would be executed. In the SQL statement that I'm creating, I want to use the 'LIKE' operator but as this uses inverted commas '', it conflicts with the inverted commas used at the start of the 'SELECT' statement.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE Application LIKE ' + @ApplicationName + ' ;'
```

Assuming '@ApplicationName = TestApp', the above dynamic SQL '@sql' variable would produce the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE Application LIKE TestApp ;
```

This would cause an error as the inverted commas doesn't exist around 'TestApp'. How can the inverted commas be created in dynamic SQL allowing 'LIKE' operator to be used? How can the the SQL Statement below be created:

```
SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE Application LIKE 'TestApp' ;
```

Comment: Even if you get that working, beware of Little Bobby Tables.  If he ever searches for `%TestApp%'; DROP TABLE LogTable; SELECT 'You were just SQL Inject Attacked` then you might get "unexpected results"!    For the love of all things, please don't use this structure, use Parameterised Queries *(AKA Prepared Statements)*.

Comment: why are you using like search without wildcard characters? also if it something simple like this why even use dynamic SQL in the first place?

Comment: I'm intending to implement an MVC App where there should be a dropdown list with pre-defined values. Selecting these values should change the @ApplicationName. I intended to use 'LIKE' so that when the empty field is selected, it replaces the 'LIKE' Operator search term with '%' to bring all.

Comment: still does not explain why you need dynamic sql

Comment: Are you creating text in app and passing it to SQL? or you building in SQL? In either case, it is better to replace it with SQL stored procedure that accept a parameter, when parameter is null return everything.

Answer (score 6):

I will use `SP_EXECUTESQL` wherein you don't want to worry about the single quotes

```
Declare  @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE Application LIKE  @ApplicationName ;'

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@ApplicationName varchar(100)',
  @ApplicationName = @ApplicationName
```

Also this avoids **SQL injection**

Comment: Also, you don't have to worry about SQL Injection Attacks.  Always, just always, use parameterised queries like this :)

Comment: and you dont need to worry if someone searches for something with a `'`in it

Comment: It's the same point I was making.  If a string literal contains a `'` then your prepared statement will handle it perfectly fine, but the OP's structure will fail due to the SQL having something such as `LIKE 'Fred's App'` *(the middle `'` causing the string to terminate and the `s App'` to be a syntax error)*.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the quotes to the SQL yourself. You can escape a single quote by having two of them:

```
SET @sql = 
    'SELECT * FROM LogTable WHERE Application LIKE ''' + @ApplicationName + ''';'
```

Comment: You just helped someone open up their code to SQL Injection Attacks.